# Change IN to EXISTS

Tags: oracle, exists

I have this 2 query :

Query #1

```
SELECT A1.clrn_id  ,A1.gpgroup ,A1.cl_id
FROM p_dtl A1
WHERE A1.PYMT_DT = TO_DATE(:1 ,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
and A1.clrn_id in (
                     select clrn_id  
                     from gp_cl_rn run  
                     where run.clrn_id = a1.clrn_id 
                     and run.finalized_ind = :2
                  )
                    AND cl_id IN 
                        ( 
                            SELECT cl_id 
                            FROM hm_sal 
                            WHERE oprt_id ='004038'  
                            AND runctrl_id = :3
                        )
```

Query #2

```
SELECT B.eid
FROM JBB B
WHERE B.eid IN 
(
    (
        SELECT eid
        FROM pbank A
        WHERE (bankid,branchid) IN 
        (
            SELECT bankid  ,branchid  
            FROM pbranch 
            WHERE sourceid = :1
            AND estat=:2
        )
        AND ESTAT = :2
        AND acct_type = :3
        AND acct_id = (
                select max(D.acct_id) 
                from pbank D 
                where D.eid = A.eid
                AND D.ESTAT = :2
                AND D.acct_type = :3)
     )
)
```

How can I change the `clrn_id` for the 1st query and `B.eid` for the 2nd query into EXISTS function?  And are the `bankid`, `branchid` and `acct_id` also changeable into EXISTS function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You *can* change this to a `where exists`, but you probably want to `join` instead:

```
SELECT B.eid
  FROM JBB B
  JOIN ( SELECT eid, estat, acct_type, acct_id
              , max(acct_id) over ( partition by eid ) as max_acct
           FROM pbank 
                ) A
    ON b.eid = a.eid
  JOIN pbranch C
    ON a.bankid = c.bankid
   AND a.branchid = c.brahchid
 WHERE c.sourceid = :1
   AND c.estat = :2
   AND a.ESTAT = :3
   AND a.acct_type = :4
   AND a.acct_id = a.max_acct
```

By using the analytic function `max()` you remove the need for a sub-select; it's also a lot clearer, I think, to do things in this manner.

---

And, your newly added query becomes:

```
SELECT A1.clrn_id, A1.gpgroup, A1.cl_id
  FROM p_dtl A1
  JOIN gp_cl_rn run
    ON A1.clrn_id = run.clrn_id
 WHERE A1.PYMT_DT = TO_DATE(:1 ,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   AND run.clrn_id = a1.clrn_id 
   AND run.finalized_ind = :2
```

I notice that you're explicitly using the `to_date()` function, which implies that you're storing a date as a string. This is bad practice and likely to cause you trouble in the longer run... avoid it if at all possible.

---

```
max(acct_id) over ( partition by eid )
```

is an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174); this does exactly the same as the aggregate function `max()`, except instead of requiring a GROUP BY, it returns the same result for *every* row in the result set.

This particular use returns the maximum `acct_id` for every `eid`. There's a whole host of analytic functions, but the best thing to do is to try it for yourself. There are also [several examples](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55) available online.

Using a JOIN is not *necessarily* quicker than a `where exists`, it just depends what you're after. As with everything I would recommend trying both and seeing what suits your particular situation more.

Generally, they have different purposes; `where exists` is designed to stop "calculating" rows when a single row that fulfils the conditions is found. JOIN, does everything. In your case as you want everything there *may* be little to chose between them but I would always use JOIN; just ensure that your indexes are correct.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the `max(acct_id) over ( partition by eid )` ?  I'm totally new to that one :)
Oh, and is there any performance differences by using the JOIN instead of EXISTS?
By the way, Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: and I think the bind variables need to be edited, the `estat` is supposed to have same bind, right?  I just edited mine :)

Comment: @RedFux227, I've updated my answer. The bind variables are correct though; you can't reuse them.

Comment: So the estat isn't supposed to hold the same variable? Thanks for the explanation, though!

Comment: Oh and so I have the option to use either JOIN or Exists, right? Both of them will return the same value, right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RedFux227, yes theoretically. I won't say "yes definitely" as this is something that you have to test; I don't have your environment.

Comment: What about the bind variable? The estat column supposed to have same bind, right?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope, it will help you:

```
SELECT B.eid
FROM JBB B
where exists
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM pbank A
    WHERE exists
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM pbranch PB
            WHERE PB.sourceid = :1
            AND PB.estat=:2
            and PB.bankid  = A.bankid
            AND PB.branchid  = A.branchid
        )
        AND ESTAT = :2
        AND acct_type = :3
        AND A.eid = B.eid
        AND acct_id = (
                select max(D.acct_id) 
                from pbank D 
                where D.eid = A.eid
                AND D.eid = B.eid
                AND D.ESTAT = :2
                AND D.acct_type = :3)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
By the way, what does SELECT 1 mean? Why don't use SELECT eid instead?

Comment: @RedFux227, it makes no difference; they're functionally equivalent, you're not going to use the value. You can use `select null...` or `select * ...` if you want. The optimizer is smart enough to know you don't want to return anything.

Comment: so I could still use select eid, am I right? I thought using select * will slow down the query hahaha

Comment: @RedFux227, no it won't. In an `exists` sub-query you can write whatever you want and it will not slow down the query... the optimizer is good.

Comment: It's depend of RDBMS engine, it's good practise to set `select 1` for performance. Maybe for ORACLE there is no difference, but for other RDBMS it will slow down a query. When you use `select *`, all columns will be returned, so it can slow down the query.Another reason: when I see `select 1` I know it's `if exists` :).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B.eid
FROM JBB B
JOIN
(
    (
        SELECT eid
        FROM pbank A
        WHERE (bankid,branchid) IN 
        (
            SELECT bankid  ,branchid  
            FROM pbranch 
            WHERE sourceid = 'BNIATB'
            AND estat='A'
        )
        AND ESTAT = 'A'
        AND acct_type = 'S'
        AND acct_id = (
                select max(D.acct_id) 
                from pbank D 
                where D.eid = A.eid
                AND D.ESTAT = 'A'
                AND D.acct_type = 'S')
     )
) C on B.eid = c.EID
```

Comment: Are you sure the two queries are equivalent?

Comment: One thing to look out for is the behavior when the inner select returns NULL values.

Comment: @ypercube Pretty close, not sure if its the correct join type though.